# Controlling the YouTube player

Tags: youtube-api

Is it possible to control somehow remotely the YouTube player using the API? I mean, for example, sending a message to forward the video by 10 seconds, or switch to the next video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

You can switch to the next video with loadVideoById/Url, cueVideoById/Url (for YouTube Embedded Player).

But IFrame Player API does not have the messaging mechanism. You should implement original code in JavaScript (Note the following).

https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/required-minimum-functionality#overlays-and-frames

> You must not display overlays, frames, or other visual elements in front of any part of a YouTube embedded player, including player controls.